# Puppet; pushing manifests to nodes without restarting puppetmasterd?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

After I update a manifest for a node; does puppetmaster automatically send the configuration to the node? If it does what is the interval and how do I change it? Where can I find more information about this?

I assume it's the `runinterval` for puppet.conf? The default setting is 1800 seconds; however I have yet to notice any configuration change since puppetmaster started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The master doesn't send the file to the node; the node checks in with the master on the run interval.

And yeah, no need to restart the master service to serve the new updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use puppet client at your node with --test --noop to see if there will be any change applied in a run, and find if you have errors preventing the puppet client run.